# Why Jakarta Validation did not automatically execute the validation and throw the exception?

Tags: java, spring-boot, validation, jakarta-ee, bean-validation

I started validating a method parameter with: if notValid then throw exception,

Then I realize that I can create my own annotations to validate parameters, and some minutes later I was looking for a library that already have those simple annotations for validating numbers for example.

I discover Jakarta Bean Validation (ex javax.validation),

so I added the following dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
    <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

I started using it by annotating a method parameter.

```
public static String toString(
                              final BigDecimal numberToFormat, 
                              @PositiveOrZero final int scale, 
                              final char decimalSeparator, 
                              final char groupingSeparator, 
                              final NumberFormatPattern numberFormatPattern) {

    String pattern = getPattern(scale, numberFormatPattern);
    return format(numberToFormat, decimalSeparator, groupingSeparator, pattern);

}
```

Starting a JUnit test and passing -1 as scale value, I was expecting an exception to be thrown, but nothing happened.

```
class NumberFormatUtilsTest {

    void _toString_INVALID_SCALE() {
        BigDecimal number = NumberUtils.toBigDecimal("123.456");
        assertThrows(ConstraintViolationException.class, () -> NumberFormatUtils.toString(number, -1, ',', '.', DECIMALS_ALWAYS));
    }

}
```

Looking into [documentation](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/bean-validation/3.0/jakarta-bean-validation-spec-3.0.html#constraintdeclarationvalidationprocess-methodlevelconstraints-parameterconstraints) I see:

> Note that declaring these constraints does not automatically cause
> their validation when the concerned methods are invoked.

Why someone should add a constraint without executing the validation?

Comment: Please read: [Can I ask only one question per post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222735/can-i-ask-only-one-question-per-post) --- "*Does anyone know any good tutorials about that?*" - [Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, **tutorial** or other off-site resource are **off-topic** for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: how do your test code look likes?

Comment: just this ? do you have any setup codes to configure bean validation before calling `NumberFormatUtils.toString()` in your test codes ?

Comment: No, I don't have, because as I said, I was expecting to be automatic, and not that I have to configure the bean validation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> No, I don't have, because as I said, I was expecting to be automatic,
> and not that I have to configure the bean validation

I am sorry that it does not work likes what you expect . It requires to configure Bean Validation and trigger the validation through the Bean Validation API. Also it does not support validating on the static method too. Quote from [this](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html_single/#_parameter_constraints) as below :

> Constraints may only be applied to instance methods, i.e. declaring
> constraints on static methods is not supported. Depending on the
> interception facility you use for triggering method validation,
> additional restrictions may apply, e.g. with respect to the visibility
> of methods supported as target of interception. Refer to the
> documentation of the interception technology to find out whether any
> such limitations exist.

Good news is spring boot already auto configure it and do all the necessary integration with Bean Validation for you, but you have to make it as a spring bean and enable the validation feature by annotating it with `@Validated`. So change to the following :

```java
@Service
@Validated
public class NumberFormatUtils{
    
    public String toString(
                              final BigDecimal numberToFormat, 
                              @PositiveOrZero final int scale, 
                              final char decimalSeparator, 
                              final char groupingSeparator, 
                              final NumberFormatPattern numberFormatPattern)

   }

}
```

And to use it , you have to get the `NumberFormatUtils` bean instance from the spring context by `@Autowired` for example , but not simply create the instance by yourself.